Error installing uiautomator2 driver with Appium due ti its peer dependecy
I have installed the appium , and tried to run the uiautomator2 driver , but it cant be recognised
I keep getting this error
appium driver update
WARN Appium Appium encountered 1 warning while validating drivers found in manifest C:\Users\rupert.fernandes.appium\node_modules.cache\appium\extensions.yaml
WARN Appium Driver "uiautomator2" has 1 potential problem:
WARN Appium   - Driver "uiautomator2" (package appium-uiautomator2-driver) may be incompatible with the current version of Appium (v2.0.1) due to its peer dependency on older Appium v^2.4.1. Please ask the developer of appium-uiautomator2-driver to update the peer dependency on Appium to v2.0.1.
usage: index.js driver update [-h] [--json] [--unsafe] driver
index.js driver update: error: the following arguments are required: driver
